# Strange issues with WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection() and Azure hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, webdeploy

This one is just weird enough to make me think that I am overlooking something obvious here.

I have an ASP.NET MVC4 application with a SQL Server 2008 database. I am using EF Code first, with code first migrations. For the MVC membership I am using the SimpleMembershipProvider.

Here is some info regarding the current state of things:

1. The database is already on Azure, and it has the latest migration run on it.
2. I can connect to the database using the connection string I have on file, so there is no issue with the connection string that I can see.
3. This has been happening intermittently throughout by various publishes of the site.
4. I am calling WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "Users", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true); in the global.asax
5. My IP address is allowed on the database server.

Here is the Application_Start() Method in the global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "Users", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
        //SeedMembership();
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        Database.SetInitializer<PTContext>(null);

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
    }
```

If I publish this to Azure, it gives me this error:

```
Login failed for user 'userName'.
This session has been assigned a tracing ID of '95f84d15-0e0c-47f8-bc04-3ae7febf5de8'.
Provide this tracing ID to customer support when you need assistance.
```

'userName' here is the username of my Sql Server that I have on azure.

Now is the strange part. If I comment out the WebSecurity line like so:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        //WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "Users", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
        //SeedMembership();
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        Database.SetInitializer<PTContext>(null);

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
    }
```

And now if I publish, It will get me to my login page (which is the default start page, so this is a good thing), but as soon as I log in, I get this error:

```
You must call the "WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection" method 
before you call any other method of the "WebSecurity" class.
This call should be placed in an _AppStart.cshtml file in the root of your site.
```

This error is not surprising, since I am obviously using WebSecurity to handle my login and membership stuff.

You can see how this is kind of a lose-lose here for me. My assumption is that the WebSecurity.Init..() line is what is causing the first error to be thrown, and it is obvious that the lack of having the code there in my app_start method is causing the second error.

Comment: try put `autoCreateTables: false` and see if the problem is the CREATE permission as @danludwig said.